# Popup Confirm box on Select change

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML form with SELECT field and when i choose option i would like to launch CONFIRM message and if i choose "yes" it should submit the form.

how can i do that?

```
<form action="index.php?page=<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>" method="post" >

    <select name="planID" onChange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose plan1</option>
            <option value="">Choose plan2</option>
            <option value="">Choose plan3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (confirm('foo')) this.form.submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php?page=<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>" method="post" id="myForm">

    <select name="planID" onchange="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose plan1</option>
            <option value="">Choose plan2</option>
            <option value="">Choose plan3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```